# Run Docker container with preset IP from Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-network

I'm trying to deploy 3 containers with Ansible, one of them contains a MySQL and I want to assure that its IP is static and well known for the other 2.

I've tried this task:

```
- name: launch mysql container
docker:
  name: my-mysql-container
  image: my-mysql-image
  ip: 172.17.0.4
  volumes:
  - "databases:/var/lib/mysql"
```

But the parameter `ip` is not supported, and the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) gives no clues.

I know that I can use the `shell` parameter to run the container with a bash command.
But is there any option to preset the IP **using the Ansible Docker module**?

Comment: Isn't `extra_hosts` parameter what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker` module is deprecated and not supported, use [docker_container](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html).
There is `networks` parameter will be available in Ansible 2.2 that might solve your problem.

BTW, why do you need ip-address to connect from other containers, you can connect via container name `my-mysql-container`, docker will resolve it for you.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to link the containers. Now using the container name to connect works like a charm.